# Having turtles verify if they own a link / have a neighbor turtle

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way for turtles to verify if they have links or neighbors?

I need a way for turtles to check if they have a link.  If the turtle does, then I need it change the variable SocialST to 1.  If the turtle does not, then it should skip.  Here is what I have devised so far...

```
to SocialStructure
ask turtles with [link-neighbors] 
[if (abs([SN] of self - [SN] of one-of link-neighbors) >= Soctol ) [Set SocialST 1]]
```

end

Comment: `[variable] of self` is never necessary: you can just use `variable` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making minimal changes to your code:

```
to updateSocialStructure
  ask turtles with [any? link-neighbors] [
    if (abs([SN - [SN] of one-of link-neighbors) >= Soctol )) [Set SocialST 1]
  ]
end
```

But do you really want `one-of`?

Comment: Ahh, that did.  Thank you for the help.

Yea, I want one-of.  I'm having my population only ask one neighbor at a time.